# Blazor trying to resolve variables in HTML before executing code?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

I am writing a practice app in Blazor , utilizing an API that I wrote. I am attempting to load user information in a "profile" page. I have the API call in a service class but the execution order seems to be weird resulting in a null reference?

Profile Page:

```
@page "/profile"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider
@inject UserService _UserService

if(user.equals(null)) 
{
    <span>@message</span>
}
else{
    <h2>Hello @user.Username</h2>

    <div class=container>
        <div class="text-center">
            <img src=""/>
            <p>@user.Bio</p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@code {
    private User? user = null;
    private string message;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

        //var currentUserId = "1";
        var currentUserId = authstate.User.Identities.First().Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "nameid").Value;
        var result = await _UserService.GetUserById(Int32.Parse(currentUserId));
        if(!result.Success)
        {
            message = result.Message;
        }
        else 
        {
            user = result.Data;
        }
    }
}
```

User class:

```
    public class User
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }      
        [JsonPropertyName("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("profilePicture")]
        public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("bio")]
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("lastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("createdAt")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
        [JsonPropertyName("lastUpdated")]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UserService class:

```
    public class UserService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _http;
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authStateProvider;

        public UserService(HttpClient http, AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider)
        {
            _http = http;
            _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<User>>> GetUsers()
        {
            var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<List<User>>>($"/User");
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<ServiceResponse<User>> GetUserById(int id)
        {
            var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<User>>($"/User/GetById/{id}");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the profile page, when I debug this, the debugger goes straight from

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var authstate = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

to

```
<h2>Hello @user.Username</h2>
```

complaining that user is null. Why isn't the function OnInitializedAsync() being fully executed before trying to render the HTML where user.Username is being called? I expect user to be null at this point because the code that sets it seems to be getting skipped?

Comment: This code won't compile, please verify. Post working code that exhibits the problem. Don't edit things out without testing. See [mre]

Comment: @HenkHolterman apologies. Code should be runnable now, I see I missed a bracket in here.

Comment: `if (user.equals(null))` is I believe the error.  User is null so you can't call Equals on it.  Use `if(user is null)`

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thanks for the suggestion, however this did not change my result.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I cleaned it up in VS and recopied it here. This is what I have in my VS and am facing this error with.

Comment: In the code you've  shown with the change to the null test `user` cannot be null - you've asserted that with the test, so `user.Username` must be null.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis : `@user.Username` will not give an error when Username is null.

Comment: With `User.Equals` the code won't even compile in VS!  So how are you running it.

Comment: User is null. Even if I change it to user.ToString() I am getting the error and my VS is telling me "user was null". When I debug this, the debugger jumps from the "var authState" line straight to the h2 line saying user is null. Which is partly what I am not understanding. When I debug I don't even get to the line where I am calling my service.

Comment: @HenkHolterman correct on that point.  The Razor compiler is forgiving.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i've added those classes to the post.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I now use `is` based on this info from MS - "When you match an expression against null, the compiler guarantees that no user-overloaded == or != operator is invoked."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Razor code has the following logic:

```
@if(user is null)
{
   // display a message
}
else
{
   // show some user info
}
```

Then you cannot get to *Show some user info* if `user` is null.  Therefore there must be something wrong with your logic.

On you second comment:

```
var authstate = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

The `await` yields, so `ComponentBase` will initiate it's first render event which is what you are seeing.  At this point `User` is null so you should see `message` (which appears to be null at this point in the proceedings - but not declared string?).

Comment: This whole thing is because I forgot my @ on my if statement..

Comment: And i didn't spot that either, though my answer above is technically correct - there was something wrong with your logic!

Comment: Interesting point here: VS still applies C# syntax colouring when you leave out the `@`. That makes this mistake pretty hard to spot.  The `e` in `equals()` was a hint, that could never compile.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis why do you say something is wrong with the logic? Working as expected now.

Comment: [In jest]The missing @